# How to terminate threads in python on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: python, multithreading

The problem is relatively simple only that I could not find any 
answer with a google search for terms:

1. How to terminate threads in python
2. How to end while loop using keyboard input in threads etc

So format of the program is this:

```
import everything necessary

def readingsomething():
      DOING SOME WORK in a infinite while loop and sleep for 1 sec

def readingsomeotherthing():
     DOING SOME WORK  in a infinite while loop and sleep for 2 sec

thread1 = thread.thread(target = readingsomething)

thread2 = thread.thread(target = readingsomeotherthing)

try:     
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start() 

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()  

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    save a file and sys.exit()
```

So when I run the program everything is smooth except when I
press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> it does not terminate as per keyboardInterrupt

I am losing the data collected as I am unable to save them.

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) when posting so that your code is easier to read for the people who will be helping you.

Comment: kindly properly indent your code - as you execute it. And what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: The code is compiling without errors and executes but it should terminate only pressing ctrl+c but it does not stop and keeps executing i think it is a problem due to sleep commands in the functions

Answer (score 0):

It is rather unclear what you're trying to do.
You're talking about loops but I see none in your code.

Also, written like that, you will first wait for thread1 to stop, then wait for thread2 to stop, make sure it's what you want.

Put a timeout inside these 'join' calls, otherwise it prevents the listening of exceptions:

```
thread1.join()
```

becomes

```
thread1.join(10)
```

You may want to think about the changes it induces on your code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it.
The loops are in the function defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the synchronized queue [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) as a pipe to send a value to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Working Python 3 example:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

def readingsomething(stop):
    while not stop.isSet():
        print('readingsomething() running')
        time.sleep(1)

def readingsomeotherthing(stop):
    while not stop.isSet():
        print('readingsomeotherthing() running')
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stop = Event()
    thread1 = Thread(target=readingsomething, args=(stop,))
    thread2 = Thread(target=readingsomeotherthing, args=(stop,))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    try:
        thread1.join()
        thread2.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('catched KeyboardInterrupt')
        stop.set()
        #save the file

    print('EXIT __main__')
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will try this out.

Comment: Since I am using python3 ,
key = input ('Press ctrl+c to  terminate') becomes
key = eval(input('press ctl+c to terminate') but i keep getting invalid syntax error on c , i trying to find why

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve the  problem in similar fashion.